# Flutter functioning incorrectly on android studio

Tags: flutter, android-studio, gradle

I am currntly getting this error on my android when I attempt anything regarding a pub upgrade. the error is as follows:

Building flutter tool...
Running pub upgrade...
Error on line 1, column 1 of pubspec.lock: Unexpected character.
╷
1 │
│ ^
╵
Error (65): Unable to 'pub upgrade' flutter tool. Retrying in five seconds... (9 tries left)

I have deleted my pubspec.lock as suggested in other articles but that did not work for me and I cannot run the app or make any flutter related commands in my terminal. flutter doctor is not working either giving and out the same error

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to be sure about the problem you are having, but I recommend you try to delete the `pubspec.lock` inside your flutter installation directory and then run a `flutter pub upgrade`

> your_flutter_directory/packages/flutter_tools/pubspec.lock